# How do I make the digits not append after a calculation has just been performed in a jquery calculator?

Tags: jquery, append, reset, digits

I have a task to create a calculator in jquery and with the help of the answers I got from the users of this site I managed to almost make it functional. One of the issues left would be that everytime after a calculation has been performed (Eg: 2+5 =7), the digits pushed afterwards are appended to the result whereseas I would want an automatical reset at the moment a new button is pressed after the final value had been shown.
This is the code:

```
var $calc = $("#calculator");
            var $display = $("#display");
            var $numbers = $("#numbers button");
            var $operators = $("#operators button");
            var $colspan = $(".colspan");

            var init = 0;
            var operand = init;
            var operation = null; 
            var afterOperation = false;

            var reset = function() {
                $display.text(init);
                operand = null;
                operation = null;
            }

            $numbers.not($('#colspan')).click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var currValue = parseFloat($display.text());
                var currValue = parseFloat(operand) + parseFloat(operation);
                  if($("#display").data("currValue") == true) { 
                    reset($(this).text()); 
                    }
                if(afterOperation == false) {
                    if($display.text() == init && $display.text().indexOf(',')<0) {
                        $display.text($(this).text());
                    } else {
                    $display.append($(this).text());
                    } 
                } else {
                    $display.text($(this).text());
                    afterOperation = false;
                }
            });
            $operators.click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var currValue = $(this).text();
                var currOperand = parseFloat($display.text());
                if(currValue != 'CE') {
                if(operation != null && !afterOperation){
                    switch(operation) {
                        case '+':
                            $display.text(operand + currOperand);
                            break;
                        case '-':
                            $display.text(operand - currOperand);
                            break;
                        case '*':
                            $display.text(operand * currOperand);
                            break;
                        case '/':
                            if(currOperand != 0) {
                                $display.text((Math.round(operand / currOperand * 100)/100).toString().replace(".",","));
                            } else {
                                alert("ERROR");
                                reset();
                            }
                            break;
                        }   
                    }
                }
                if(currValue != '=') {
                        operation = currValue;
                } else {
                        operation = null;
                        afterOperation = false;
                        return;
                }
                if(currValue != 'C') {
                   operation = currValue;
                } else {
                        $display.text(init);
                }   
                if(currValue != '←') {
                        operation = currValue;
                } else {
                        $display.text($display.text().substring(0,$display.text().length-1));
                }
                if(operand = parseFloat($display.text())) {
                        afterOperation = true;
                } else {
                    reset();
                }

            });
    });
```

I am not sure where the problem is since I tried to aplly the reset variable both in the $numbers.not- as well in the $operators function. It did not do the trick. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is bit tricky. Add a class to the `$display` when you add result in it using:

```
$display.text(operand + currOperand).addClass('result');
```

On click of every button check if the `$display` is having class result then clear the field using:

```
if($display.hasClass('result')){
    $display.val('');
}
```

Hope you get the idea that what can be done. I don't have your HTML code so may be I am not precise.

Comment: Hello, many many thanks for the hint. I added the code and it works...partially. When I now make a calculation, get the result and click on another digit for a new calculation -the newly clicked digit does not append to the result anymore. I thought it was great until I wanted to write the number 23 and the 3 replaced the 2. Or if I want to have 2457 the 4 will now replace the 2, the 5 the 4, the 7 the 5. What am I doing wrong?